# spring data repository with native named query on unMapped POJO

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a POJO named company which is mapped to a database table named company
I have a native query with only two fields (company from legacy reasons has lots of eager mapping which I would like to remove)

the system is working with spring data 
I would like to map as a native query and only fill these two scalars to my list of companies
how can I do it using the CompanyRepository?

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "company")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
  @NamedNativeQuery(
      name = "getDefaultBuyers",
      query =
          "SELECT c.id as id ,c.name as name"
              + "FROM complex query with non mapped tables "
      resultSetMapping = "getDefaultBuyersMapping")

 @SqlResultSetMapping(
      name = "getDefaultBuyers",
      columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "name"),@ColumnResult(name = "id")})
public class Company {
 @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 32)
 protected String id;
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
 protected String name;
//diffrent properties 
}

@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository
    extends JpaRepository<Company, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Company>{}
```

**EDIT**
I dont think it's elegant, but this one works, can someone help me do it more elegant

````
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository
    extends JpaRepository<Company, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Company>{
@Query(
      value =
          "SELECT c.id as id ,c.name as name FROM bidder_config b, native_version n, company c WHERE ...",
      nativeQuery = true)
  Object[][] getDefaultBuyers(); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

apparently there is an issue in spring data which resolved like this :

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository
    extends JpaRepository<Company, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Company>{
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
  List<DefaultBuyerDTO> getDefaultBuyers();
}
```

see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/jpa21#support-for-custom-sqlresultsetmapping-with-constructorresult for more info